Radial geodesic passing through center
In my class we briefly treated the following proposition:

Given a geodesic ball $B=exp_{p}(\bar{B})$ and $p,q\in B$, there exists a unique geodesic $\gamma:[0,1] \to B$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma(1)=q$. Moreover, $\gamma(t)=exp_{p}(tv)$ with $v$ unique in $\bar{B}$. $\gamma$ is called geodetic ray.

the existence is quite easy, take the "moreover" part with $v=(exp)^{-1}(q)$. The problem is the unicity: taken another $\tau$ desired, call $\tau'(0)=w$, notice that $\tau$ and $t\to exp_{p}(tw)$ have the same initial point so they coincide. To show that $w=v$, I'd like that $w\in \bar{B}$, following the thesis for the bijection $exp_{p}$. But I can't see that, my only idea was that I can write $\tau(t)=exp_{p}(s(t))$ with $s(t)\in\bar{B}$ for every $t$ and inside $\bar{B}$ I would have $s(t)=tw$. If $w\notin \bar{B}$, there would exists $\bar{t}$ such that $\bar{t}w\in\partial \bar{B}$ , so for continuity $s(\bar{t})\in\partial \bar{B}$. Absurd. I can't think of other proofs.
My references are Do carmo's and Lee's book. I've found a related question, but it was mainly focused on showing the minimizing property of geodesics and it was suggested a proof at pag 32 prop. 3.5 < http://perso.eleves.ens-rennes.fr/people/Gwendal.Soisnard/Rapports_2016/Thomas_Franzinetti_38996.pdf >, but this proof is quite unclear. I can't see why there exists $t_0$ such that $exp_{p}(t_ow)\in U\backslash \tau[0,1]$ and why it is the absurd part.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Note your typo. $\gamma(1)=q$? Do you know that $\exp_p$ is a diffeomorphism on a suitable neighborhood of $0\in T_pM$?

@Tedshifrin corrected now

Great. Does the rest of my comment not resolve the uniqueness issue?

@TedShifrin not much. Would you mind writing this part completely? I would use the diffeomorphism just to say $v=w$ if $w\in\bar{B}$

I cannot decipher your issue. What is the assumption on $\bar B$?
